# HTML How to align an image to right and then with margin/padding? Or center with align one x px to the right and the other image slightly to the left

Tags: html

I am trying to set up a footer and wrote some html to align one image right and one to the left. The problem is when you zoom out it is TOO much to the sides and I want them to be more centered. it looks fine when you zoom in but again, not so nice when you dont.

How can I align something to the right but have 10% or 100 px movement towards the center or another way: How can I center something but then move it say 150 px more to the right?

Comment: I got help with this one btw.

Comment: trying to add the code that worked but was not allowed

Answer (score 0):

So by using th

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
footer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 110px;
    text-align: center;
}

footer img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}

footer #footer-riba {
    left: 7cm;
}

footer #footer-intbau {
    right: 7cm;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /* For desktop: */
 footer-riba{
 display:none;
 }
}

</style>
 


<footer>
    <img id="footer-riba" src="xxxxx.png">xxxxx | 
    <img id="footer-intbau" src="xxxxxx.png">
</footer>
```